# How can I write a program to generate a sorting decision tree?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science, decision-tree

In class we were given a simple decision tree for sorting 3 elements (a,b,c).

[image]
<sub>(source: [brpreiss.com](https://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/img2116.gif))</sub>

While looking at this, it makes sense to me. I was able to follow it.

However, I now have to make a decision tree for 4 elements (a,b,c,d) and the number of leafs just shot up to 24.

I'm struggling approaching the decision tree in a methodical way that helps me keep track and of the elements I'm suppose to be comparing at each branch.

What is a methodical way of approaching the construction of a larger decision tree?  I'd even be willing to write a program to spit out the possible leafs-structure if I knew how to.

Comment: +1 for the diagram.  I'm just now reading about decision trees and this is helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into S[orting Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). It should be possible to convert the optimal sorting network for a given number of inputs into a decision tree, I think.

Alternately, you could take a given sorting algorithm and step through it, creating a new branch at each comparison.

Finally, you could do this in reverse - for example, by taking a merge-sort type approach: Lay out all 24 possible sort orders at the bottom of the tree. Pick a comparison, and partition the leaves into two sets based on the outcome. Repeat recursively for each branch until you only have one leaf per branch.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of algorithm has been described by Charles Forgy: see the [Rete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm). (I'm sorry, the article in WP is certainly not a quick answer but it might be a good start)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, *in this case*, is to extend the existing tree. A depth-3 tree can sort for up to `2^3=8` different outcomes, which is enough to sort 3 elements, since `3! = 6` and `6 <= 8`. To sort 4 elements you need at least depth 5: `4! <= 2^5`. We can structure the two new, lowest levels to decide where to insert the `d`, given that `a`, `b` and `c` are already sorted by your existing net.

Assuming that `x`, `y` and `z` are sorted, so that `x<y<z` you can use this net to add a new element `d` at its correct position:

```
// note: read from right to left
d<x<y<z -[yes]- (d<x)? -[yes]-- (d<y) -
x<d<y<z -[no]-/               /
x<y<d<z -[yes]- (d<z)? -[no]-/
x<y<z<d -[no]-/
```

So you can essentially take your existing tree, replicate it 4 times, and replace each current leaf with the above sub-tree, in each case replacing `x`,`y` and `z` with the order of `a`, `b` and `c` in the current leaf.

Note that, while this works for your particular case, and yields a minimal tree, appending subtrees to insert "the next element" will not yield minimal-height sorting trees for other cases. For example, to sort `a,b,c,d,e`, the minimal height would be 7, as `5! = 120` and `7^2 = 128`. However, a subtree to place an `e` into an already-sorted list of 4 elements would need, by itself, at least depth 3 (as there are 5 possible insertion positions) - so we can easily build a `5+3 = 8`-depth tree, but would need another approach to build a valid depth-7 tree.

For a general discussion, the link on sorting networks in [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459618/15472) is very relevant: you can build a sorting tree from a network by reading the network from left to right, creating a node for each connection, and at that point, considering two variants of the network as children: one where the swap has been made (say, `a<b` is false, so now `a` and `b` get swapped), and another where it is not needed (because `a<b`). The depth of the sorting decision tree is that of its sorting network, and according to that page, while there *is* an algorithm to generate logarithmic-depth trees/networks (AKS), it is by no means simple.